# my program is giving me warning (Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run)

Tags: functional-programming, f#

my program is giving me warning (Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run), does this have to do with the fact that I need to put the deposit member before the withdraw member (as there would not be anything in the program to use)

```
type Account =

    {accountNumber:string; mutable balance:float} 

    member this.Withdraw(cash:float) = 
        if cash > this.balance then
            Console.WriteLine("Insufficient Funds. The Amount you wish to withdraw is greater than your current account balance.")
        else
            this.balance <- this.balance - cash
            Console.WriteLine("You have withdrawn £" + cash.ToString() + ". Your balance is now: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Deposit(cash:float) =
        this.balance <- this.balance + cash
        Console.WriteLine("£" + cash.ToString() + " Cash Deposited. Your new Balance is: £" + this.balance.ToString())

    member this.Print() = 
        Console.WriteLine("Account Number: " + this.accountNumber)
        Console.WriteLine("Balance: £" + this.balance.ToString())
```

the program should, define an f# type named Account that contains an accountNumber (string), and balance (float) field. the type should include methods to withdraw and deposit money into the account along with a print member that displays the field values on a single line within the console. If the withdrawal amount is greater than the account balance then the transaction should be cancelled and a suitable message displayed.

Comment: This code seems to explain how an Account is represented & how to do various things with it, but as the error message says, never tries to actually *do* any of those things.  For example, what code gives the information about the initial account (number & balance)?

Comment: Have you defined an [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point)?

Comment: Thanks, How do I add an entry point my example above, if you could use my code above and show an example, e.g. what the accountNumber would be, and what the balance would be (maybe the account balance was 5 at the start of the program.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any program in any programming language needs an entry point. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/entry-point) the doc for `main` in F#.

Most bare F# programs will start with a `main` function that looks something like this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    printfn "Arguments passed to function : %A" args
    // Return 0. This indicates success.
    0
```

You'll want to put your own logic in `main`.

Comment: thanks, how would I use this entry point in my example above?

Comment: You would add it to an F# source file (.fs) in your project. Maybe a `Program.fs` file, or `Main.fs`. The attribute `[<EntryPoint>]` will tell the compiler that the `main` function is the desired entry point.

Comment: Thanks I ried don't think I'm doing it right, How do I add an entry point my example above, if you could use my code above and show an example, e.g. what the accountNumber would be, and what the balance would be (maybe the account balance was 5 at the start of the program.